# Diálogo Toast de sucesso no envio do formulário com PHP

Tags: php, materialize

Estou criando um formulário para meu site pessoal, onde o usuário irá preencher com nome, sobrenome, email, senha e mensagem e essas informações serão enviadas para meu email pessoal.

O envio do formulário já esta funcionando perfeitamente, com a Lib PHPMailer do PHP.

```
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {

    echo "Enviado com sucesso!"
}
```

**No entanto eu gostaria que ao invés do `echo "Enviado com sucesso!"`, fosse exibido uma mensagem de sucesso ou insucesso com o Diálogo Toast do Framework materialize.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem simples, faça desta forma:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "<script>
            $(function(){
                Materialize.toast('Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo."' , 2200)
            }
            });  
    </script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>
            $(function(){
                Materialize.toast('Enviado com sucesso!' , 2200)
            }
            });  
    </script>";
}
```

Ou

**envia-msg.php**

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
    header("Location: pag_onde_vc_mostra_a_msg.php?acao=fail");
} else {
    header("Location: pag_onde_vc_mostra_a_msg.php?acao=ok");
}
```

**pag_onde_vc_mostra_a_msg.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['acao'])){
    $msg = "";
    if($_GET['acao'] == 'ok'){
        $msg = 'Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo."';
    }
    if($_GET['acao'] == 'fail'){
        $msg = 'Enviado com sucesso!';
    }
    echo "  <script>
                $(function(){
                    Materialize.toast('".$msg."' , 2200)
                });  
            </script>";
}
```

Comment: Oi Wictor seu script realmente me parece ser a forma correta, porém quando eu clico no botão ENVIAR eu sou enviado para o arquivo `envia-msg.php` (responsável pela lógica para enviar email). Mas o que acontece é que eu gostaria de ficar na mesma página, apenas com as mensagem de Toast.

Comment: Não sua pagina envia-msg você vai ter que usar o comando header("Location: pagina_onde_voce_esta?acao=ok.php") e passar via get ok ou fail e na sua pagina principal verificar se existe if(isset($_GET['acao'])) e verificar se foi ok ou não, assim você coloca as mensagens na pagina principal.

Comment: @MatheusNascimento fiz uma alteração de acordo com o seu comentário.

Comment: Perfeito... Obrigado!